# xfce gtk themes problem

Tags: linux, xfce, gtk, theme

I'm using "delorean-dark-theme.3.8" (wich support gtk2 and 3) on xfce, all xfce gtk2 and some gtk3 apps looks great
[image: Xfburn xfce app]

but some gtk3 apps especially gnome apps looks terrible button backgrounds and spacing between menu bar items are messed up 
[image: gnome gtk3 app running on xfce 4.12]

gtk2 version: 2.24.30-2
gtk3 version: 3.20.6-1

I tried some other themes but i'm still getting same result
so why spacing is messed up?

Answer (score 3):

GTK 3.20 made some [significant changes](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2015/11/20/a-gtk-update/) to the way that themes are handled. Unfortunately, the Delorean theme has not been updated to support GTK 3.20. You need to use a theme that is GTK 3.20 compliant like the [Vertex](https://github.com/horst3180/vertex-theme) or [Arc](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme) themes (or petition the Delorean theme author to make the theme GTK 3.20 compliant).